# How to install python and a working ide on the MacBook Air M1

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, spyder, apple-m1

Sorry in Advance. I do not understand at all how python, an ide like Spyder or pycharm and e.g. anaconda interact.

What I first tried to do is simply downloading anaconda navigator. I started Spyder. Unfortunately there is a lagging issue for MacOs Big Sur that makes Spyder unusable. A solution to that is to download a dmg file for Spyder. I did that and the lagging issue was gone. Unfortunately I think that anaconda and Spyder do not interact anymore. Therefore I cannot install e.g. pytorch via conda install. Also pip install is not possible because the command is not recognized.

Then I downloaded pycharm but I got the error message "invalid Python SDK". I don't now how to solve this.

I have already wasted several hours setting this up and I just don't know what to do now. Can anyone please guide me through this?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry that your first time experience with Python was so painful. To connect the Spyder version that comes with our dmg installer with your Anaconda installation, please follow the instructions in [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7Njb3xO4Fw). If you have any more problems, please let me know here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I ended up using the Spyder version provided by anaconda. installing the following packages solves somehow the lagging issue for me:
 
`pip install PyQt5` 
`pip install PyQtWebEngine`


See https://mathtuition88.com/2020/11/29/spyder-typing-delay/

Answer (score 0):

1. Go here: https://www.python.org/ and download+install the latest version of Python 3. You can now access it as `python3` from your terminal.
2. Go here: https://code.visualstudio.com/ and download+install VSCode. You now have an IDE.
3. Install the Python plugin for VSCode.
4. Good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Download Python 3.x (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-396/) and choose macOS 64-bit universal2 installer
2. Download PyCharm Community (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=mac) and choose .dmg (Apple Silicon)

[image]

Comment: I did this. But as mentioned I got the error message above. I somehow solved it though. I am trying to install pytorch through conda install (not sure how pycharm knows about anaconda)  but its "examining conflicts" forever. Any idea on that?

Comment: I installed PyCharm on M1 without problem. And many other people did it. I wonder if you tried too many options, without cleaning up the mess that non-working solution have created. Without more data we cannot help. Remove all things that are not working, and try again. And ask only for one problem (depending the tool you want), else it will be a nightmare to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple to run Python on Mac is download Anaconda Navigator[Image of Anaconda navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUEdY.png) and access Spyder through Amaconda. Following is link to install Anaconda

https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution

Personally I have tried many methods to install python on mac but every time I got different issue, finally settled with Anaconda